# Map retorna valores diferentes pra mesma chave | JAVA

Tags: java, map

Olá, meu programa deve ler um arquivo csv e inserir cada player em um map<id, Lista>.
O map retorna valores diferentes para a mesma chave a cada iteração.

Sou iniciante em Java e não estou conseguindo resolver esse problema. Encontrei questões parecidas, mas envolviam chaves duplicadas, o que não parece ser o caso pois o playerId muda a cada iteração.

```
    public static void readDataSet(Map<Integer, List<String>> players) throws IOException {
    
    String strFile = "./datasets/players.csv";
    
    Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(strFile));
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withSkipLines(1).build();
    
    List<String[]> lines = csvReader.readAll();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    
    
    for(String[] line : lines) {
        
        
        //Convert the strid to int
        int playerId = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        
        values.add(line[1]);
        values.add(line[2]);
        
        
        //Insert in the map
        players.put(playerId, values);
        
        
        //Imprime valores diferentes pra mesma chave
        System.out.println(players.get(158023));
        
        values.clear();
        
    }

Saída:
[David Kjær Kruse, CM]
[Ryan Hillier, ST]
[Ryan Law, LB]
[Saleh Al Saeed, CM]
[Wassim Aouachria, CAM, ST]
[Jake Young, ST]
[Joe Wright, GK]
[Jean Belehouan, LB]

Deveria ser:
[Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini, RW, ST, CF]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nessa linha você está adicionando o objeto `List<String> values` como valor para todas as chaves.

```java
//Insert in the map
players.put(playerId, values);
```

Porém quando você faz isso está passando uma **referência** para o objeto `values`, só existe uma instância dele. Ou seja, toda iteração você está usando e alterando o mesmo objeto.

```java
// Aqui você está adicionando valores
values.add(line[1]);
values.add(line[2]);

// Aqui você está limpando o objeto `values`
values.clear();
```

Então o que acontece é que quando você chama `System.out.println(players.get(158023));` na verdade você vai printar o estado atual da lista `values` naquela iteração, por isso ela está mudando sempre. Uma iteração você adiciona valores, faz o print, limpa a lista, e isso se repete a cada iteração.

Segue um exemplo de como resolver o problema:

```java
    for(String[] line : lines) {

        // Coloque o values aqui dentro
        // pois você vai criar uma instância nova a cada iteração
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        int playerId = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        
        values.add(line[1]);
        values.add(line[2]);
        
        players.put(playerId, values);
        
        // Não faz sentido esse print aqui, você pode colocar após o for
        // System.out.println(players.get(158023));
        
        // Retirar o clear, senão você vai sempre limpar a lista que está como referência
        // values.clear();
        
    }
    System.out.println(players.get(158023));
```

Comment: Entendiii, muito obrigado!

Comment: @IagoTonello caso tenha resolvido o problema com esse comentário marque a resposta como aceita para ajudar outras pessoas.